# Convert interface{} to int

Tags: go

I'm trying to get a value from a JSON and cast it to int but it doesn't work, and I don't know how to do it properly.

Here is the error message:

```
...cannot convert val (type interface {}) to type int: need type assertion
```

And the code:

```
    var f interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &f)
    if err != nil {
        utility.CreateErrorResponse(w, "Error: failed to parse JSON data.")
        return
    }

    m := f.(map[string]interface{})

    val, ok := m["area_id"]
    if !ok {
        utility.CreateErrorResponse(w, "Error: Area ID is missing from submitted data.")
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Type = %v", val)   // <--- Type = float64
    iAreaId := int(val)                // <--- Error on this line.
    testName := "Area_" + iAreaId      // not reaching here
```

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Instead of

```
iAreaId := int(val)
```

you want a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
iAreaId := val.(int)
iAreaId, ok := val.(int) // Alt. non panicking version
```

The reason why you cannot [convert](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) an interface typed value are these rules in the referenced specs parts:

> Conversions are expressions of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and `x` is an expression that can be converted to type T.

...

> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:
>
> 1. x is assignable to T.
> 2. x's type and T have identical underlying types.
> 3. x's type and T are unnamed pointer types and their pointer base types have identical underlying types.
> 4. x's type and T are both integer or floating point types.
> 5. x's type and T are both complex types.
> 6. x is an integer or a slice of bytes or runes and T is a string type.
> 7. x is a string and T is a slice of bytes or runes.

But

```
iAreaId := int(val)
```

is *not* any of the cases 1.-7.

Comment: Good answer! Language spec is always the best place to look for an answer!

Answer (score 61):

I am assuming: If you sent the JSON value through browser then any number you sent that will be the type float64 so you cant get the value directly int in golang.

So do the conversion like:

```
//As that says: 
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Type = %v", val) // <--- Type = float64

var iAreaId int = int(val.(float64))
```

This way you can get exact value what you wanted.

Comment: You are 100% right @Mujibur, but any reason, as there is integer type in JSON specs

Comment: @kamal that's because JSON, uses Javascript syntax and definitions. JavaScript only supports 64-bit floating point numbers. Ref# https://javascript.info/number

Comment: This may lose precision

Answer (score 7):

Adding another answer that uses `switch`... There are more comprehensive examples out there, but this will give you the idea.

In example, `t` becomes the specified data type within each `case` scope. Note, you have to provide a `case` for only one type at a type, otherwise `t` remains an `interface`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var val interface{} // your starting value
    val = 4

    var i int // your final value

    switch t := val.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = t
    case int8:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case int16:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case int32:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case int64:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("%t == %T\n", t, t)
        // // not covertible unless...
        // if t {
        //  i = 1
        // } else {
        //  i = 0
        // }
    case float32:
        fmt.Printf("%g == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("%f == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case uint8:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case uint16:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case uint32:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case uint64:
        fmt.Printf("%d == %T\n", t, t)
        i = int(t) // standardizes across systems
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%s == %T\n", t, t)
        // gets a little messy...
    default:
        // what is it then?
        fmt.Printf("%v == %T\n", t, t)
    }

    fmt.Printf("i == %d\n", i)
}
```

Comment: For `case string`, you can use `strconv.ParseFloat(t, 32)` and then cast the result to an `int`

Answer (score 5):

I whole-heartedly agree with [zzzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065241/zzzz)'s **type assertion** answer and I strongly prefer that way over others.  That said, here's what I've had to do when the preferred method has not worked... (long story related to cross-serialization of data).  You can even chain this into a `switch` statement with `case errInt == nil` and similar expressions.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    var v interface{}
    v = "4"

    i, errInt := strconv.ParseInt(v.(string), 10, 64)

    if errInt == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%d is a int", i)
        /* do what you wish with "i" here */
    }
}
```

Like I said above, try **type assertion** first before trying this way.

Comment: As pointed out, if parsing JSON, value will be float. In that case, use `strconv.ParseFloat(v.(string), 64)` instead. You may want to change variable names too, say `errFloat`.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you need

```golang
func TransToString(data interface{}) (res string) {
    switch v := data.(type) {
    case float64:
        res = strconv.FormatFloat(data.(float64), 'f', 6, 64)
    case float32:
        res = strconv.FormatFloat(float64(data.(float32)), 'f', 6, 32)
    case int:
        res = strconv.FormatInt(int64(data.(int)), 10)
    case int64:
        res = strconv.FormatInt(data.(int64), 10)
    case uint:
        res = strconv.FormatUint(uint64(data.(uint)), 10)
    case uint64:
        res = strconv.FormatUint(data.(uint64), 10)
    case uint32:
        res = strconv.FormatUint(uint64(data.(uint32)), 10)
    case json.Number:
        res = data.(json.Number).String()
    case string:
        res = data.(string)
    case []byte:
        res = string(v)
    default:
        res = ""
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) to help you determine the type and then convert.

```golang
func i2num(a interface{}) (interface{}, error) { // interface to number
    aValue := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    switch aValue.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        return aValue.Int(), nil
    case reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64:
        return aValue.Float(), nil
    case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
        return aValue.Uint(), nil
    case reflect.Bool:
        if a == true {
            return 1, nil
        }
        return 0, nil
    case reflect.String:
        return strconv.ParseFloat(aValue.String(), 64)
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("type error")
    }
}
```

[image: Go Playground]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do type assertion for converting your interface{} to int value.

```
iAreaId := val.(int)
iAreaId, ok := val.(int)
```

More information is [available](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Answer (score 1):

use `cast.ToInt(anyValue)`

I needed that, because the nasty endpoint which I need to use has a bug and sometimes is returning an integer as a string, sometimes as float64

https://github.com/spf13/cast

Answer (score 0):

To better understand the type conversion, look at the code below:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func foo(a interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(a.(int))  // conversion of interface into int
}
func main() {
    var a int = 10
    foo(a)
}
```

This code executes perfectly and converts interface type to int type

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary expression
>   x.(T) asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
>   More precisely, if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must implement the (interface) type of x; otherwise the type assertion is invalid since it is not possible for x to store a value of type T. If T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x implements the interface T.

Going back to your code, this

`iAreaId := val.(int)`

should work good. If you want to check error occured while conversion, you can also re-write above line as

`iAreaId, ok := val.(int)`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that can help with type convertions
https://github.com/KromDaniel/jonson

```
js := jonson.New([]interface{}{55.6, 70.8, 10.4, 1, "48", "-90"})

js.SliceMap(func(jsn *jonson.JSON, index int) *jonson.JSON {
    jsn.MutateToInt()
    return jsn
}).SliceMap(func(jsn *jonson.JSON, index int) *jonson.JSON {
    if jsn.GetUnsafeInt() > 50{
        jsn.MutateToString()
    }
    return jsn
}) // ["55","70",10,1,48,-90]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I did this. Not the best way but simplest way I know how.

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Print(addTwoNumbers(5, 6))
}

func addTwoNumbers(val1 interface{}, val2 interface{}) int {
    op1, _ := val1.(int)
    op2, _ := val2.(int)

    return op1 + op2
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Best avoid casting by declaring f to be f the correct type to correspond to the JSON.