# Golang json error convertering int from json

Tags: go

I'm trying to do a simple unmarshall and extracting the int information from the code below. I found a link from another stackoverflow : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041334/convert-interface-to-int-in-golang). Though, it doesn't help in my case. the program according to ideone think the data is a float.

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

func main(){
    byt := []byte(`{"status": "USER_MOVED_LEFT", "id":1, "x":5, "y":3}`)
    var dat map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    num := dat["id"].(int)
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

Comment: JSON doesn't have an integer type. Numbers are unmarshaled as a float64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are converting your `byt` to `map[string]interfaec{}` the default value of the number will be `float64`.

```
func main(){
    byt := []byte(`{"status": "USER_MOVED_LEFT", "id":1, "x":5, "y":3}`)
    var dat map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(dat["id"])) // print the type of value
    num := dat["id"].(float64)
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

But you can also change this behavior by converting your `byt` which is your data to a `struct` like this :

```
type myStruct struct {
    Status string
    Id     int
    x      int
    y      int
}

func main() {
    byt := []byte(`{"status": "USER_MOVED_LEFT", "id":1, "x":5, "y":3}`)
    dat := myStruct{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(dat.Id))
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", dat.Id)

}
```